# Can't use fastq-dump from SRA Toolkit because can't locate XML/LibXML.pm in @INC

Tags: xml, bin, fastq

I am trying to use fastq-dump function from SRA Toolkit Package https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/sra.cgi?view=toolkit_doc&f=st 
I got error

> > Can't locate XML/LibXML.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::LibXML module) (@INC contains: /Users/darinaobukhova/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Users/darinaobukhova/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 /Users/darinaobukhova/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Users/darinaobukhova/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2 .) at ./fastq-dump line 13.
> >     BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./fastq-dump line 13.

I installed XML::LibXML module using

> > cpan install XML::LibXML

However, I keep on getting the same error.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem with SRA Toolkit 2.10 by complete installation according to

https://github.com/ncbi/sra-tools/issues/219#issuecomment-524331336